# Urban Terror not launching on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, urban-terror

I just downloaded [Urban Terror](http://urbanterror.info) and for some reason it won't launch on my Mac. The icon appears in the dock for a second and then quits itself.

**EDIT**: I am running Mac OS X version 10.6.5 and Urban Terror version 4.1

**EDIT2**: I just ran Urban Terror from the Terminal and this is the error I get:

```
ioQ3 1.35urt macosx-i386 Dec 19 2007
----- FS_Startup -----
Going through search path...

----------------------
0 files in pk3 files
Sys_Error: Couldn't load default.cfg
```

Comment: Which version of Urban Terror is that, and which version of OSX?

Comment: @Danny I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> 0 files in pk3 files
> ```

The game's search path is incorrect, as you might have guessed. Apparently, in your case, it is empty -- thus, no game files are found and the game cannot launch.

Since there is no configuration file I can find for the search path, I have to guess it looks in the current directory. `cd` into the game's folder, launch it from there and then try again.

---

After some chat discussion, we found out that you didn't fully install the game, but only copied the `ioUrbanTerror.app` folder. At least a few other files are required: the `q3ut4` folder (which contains the actual game data) and the `qkey` file at the very least are also needed.